# How would I check if a specific column name exists in a different worksheet. If not, create it?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm building a macro to restructure raw databases into new structured databases.

It looks for specific Measures (Value, Volume etc) in the raw data sheet and then checks if they exist in the New Data sheet.

If they exist, it pulls data from Raw Data into the New Data.

The "Raw Data" sheet:
[image: IMG1]

For example, I want to implement a code that starts from the top cell until it finds a measure like "Value" and then checks in the "New Data" sheet if it exists. If it does, it pastes data from the first Raw Data below "Value. If not, it creates a new column with the header "Value".

The "New Data" sheet:
[image: IMG2]

Here's my code:

```
Sub test()

    Dim datash As Worksheet
    Dim datarng As Range
    Dim tsh As Worksheet
    Dim startrng As Range
    Dim endrng As Range
    Dim copyrng As Range
    Dim r2 As Range

    'Set tsh = Sheets.Add
    'ActiveSheet.Name = "Data"

    Set datash = ActiveSheet
    Set datarng = datash.Cells(6, 2)
    Set startrng = datarng

    Do Until datarng = ""
       Set datarng = datarng.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    Set endrng = datarng(0, 1)    
    Set copyrng = datash.Range(startrng, endrng)

    Dim rng2 As Range

    Set rng2 = datash.Cells(5, 3)

    Dim measurestr As String
    Dim periodstr As String

    Do Until rng2 = ""
        measurestr = rng2(0, 1).Value
        periodstr = rng2.Value
        datash.Range(datash.Cells(startrng.Row, rng2.Column), datash.Cells(endrng.Row, rng2.Column)).Copy

        Set rng2 = rng2.Offset(0, 1)

        ' look for measures in the Data sheet
        Set r2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, findcol(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DEMO FOOD+OIL"), "VALUE (€)"))

        Do Until r2 = measuresrt.Value Or r2 = ""
            Set r2 = r2.Offset(0, 1)
        Loop

        'copyrng.Copy Sheets("Data").Range("A1")

        Stop



End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you have a list of all headers you want?  Does the New Data sheet exist, or will that be programmatically generated if it does not?

Comment: The New Data sheet already exists. There is no specific list, because the datasets we get vary. Insted I though it would be better to "scan" the Raw Data sheet for measures, and then add them to the New Data sheet if they dont exist. For the time being, my code loops through the cells, from left to right, copying (or trying to ) the whole column.

Comment: Updated my answer to utilize the new data first column.

Answer (score 0):

A quick mock up, not perfectly fitting for you:

```
dim i as long, arr as variant, findstr as string, strcols as long, strcold as long
arr = array("Measure","Value") 'etc., you get the idea
for i = lbound(arr) to ubound(arr) step 1
    findstr = arr(i).value
    with sheets("raw data")
        strcols = .Columns(1).Find(What:=findstr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
    end with
    with sheets("new data")
        if strcols > 0 then strcold = .Columns(1).Find(What:=findstr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
    end with
    sheets("new data").columns(strcold).value = sheets("raw data").columns(strcols).value
next i
```

strcols = string column source, strcold = string column destination... lets you search on both, find the column number, then value=value.

---

**Edit1:**

Updating to use the first column of sheets("new data")

```
dim i as long, lc as long, findstr as string, strcols as long
lc = sheets("new data").cells(1,sheets("new data").columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
for i = 1 to lc step 1
    findstr = sheets("new data").cells(1,i).value
    with sheets("raw data")
        strcols = .Columns(1).Find(What:=findstr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
        if strcols > 0 then sheets("new data").columns(i).value = .columns(strcols).value
    end with
next i
```